# Swift how to open many URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I want to make an app that opens many URL schemes.
To make it, I tried some ways:

1. I used `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`. 
   But this way I must add the URL scheme in `info.plist`. 
   And in `info.plist` I can add a maximum of 50 URL schemes. 
   (I want to add over 50 URL schemes)
2. I tried using `WKWebView`. 
   But The `WKWebView` doesn't handle non-http URL schemas. 
   The webview only opens http, https.

I want to open over 50 URL schemes, what should I do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I read this article about the 50 schemes limitation you have mentioned.

https://book.hacktricks.xyz/mobile-pentesting/ios-pentesting/ios-custom-uri-handlers-deeplinks-custom-schemes

It says that you need to add the schemes only if you use canOpenURL (the system method that is called in order to check if the apps are installed on the device). So, maybe you can use another check instead of canOpenURL, and this way you don't need to add the schemes to info.plist

You can always check the Bool value that is passed to the completion handler of UIApplication.shared.open(...) in order to tell if the other app was opened or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SafariServices` framework. The code would look like that if you call it from some view controller:

```
if let url = URL(string: "<your_url>") {
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but `SafariServices` also doesn't handle non-http URL schemas.  
```*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.'```

Comment: Then you have to use URL schemes.